# Fitnesse field not present in DB

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, dbfit

```
| script | Db Slim Select Query | select cust_name from customer where cust_id = 70903 |
| check | data; | cust_name | 0 | JAMES SMITH |
```

The one above works but the one below doesn't.

```
|Query:Db Slim Select Query | select cust_id, cust_name from customer where cust_id = 70903 |
| cust_id | cust_name |
| 70903   | JAMES SMITH |
```

The message I got was

```
Query:Db Slim Select Query  select cust_id, cust_name from customer where cust_id = 70903
cust_id                     cust_name
[70903] missing             JAMES SMITH
field cust_id not present   field cust_name not present
```

Did I missing something obilvous? according to the markfink's example this should not have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a simple Query table:

```
| query   | select cust_id, cust_name from customer where cust_id = 70903 |
| cust_id | cust_name   |
| 70903   | JAMES SMITH |
```

If this doesn't help try to follow the query examples on this page: https://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/reference.html#query

Comment: we are not using query, we are using db slim. it is different. the above I already know, simple google search can get bunch of query examples....

Comment: Ok, then your question tags are misleading.